# Заголовок списка

Tags: html, html5, ul

Насколько корректно будет использовать заголовок `<h1>` для списка `<ul>` . К примеру вот так:

```html
<ul><h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Работает как надо, но с точки зрения синтаксиса и логики уместно ли использовать таким образом заголовки?

Comment: Нельзя, внутри ul можно только li

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так делать не следует, ибо этот код не будет валидным.

[Валидатор W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) скажет, что это ошибка:

> Error: Element h1 not allowed as child of element ul in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: тогда просто нужно писать <h1> до <ul> и только так?

Comment: @TylerManing верно, ибо структура `ul > li` как-бы единое логическое целое.

Comment: понял, благодарю за помощь)